# Computing PARI Group ID in Sage

Tags: sagemath

I am hoping to compute the PARI Group ID for (1) a group and (2) a semi direct group constructor in Sage:

(1)

```
    G = PermutationGroup([(1, 3, 2)], [(2, 3, 4)], [(1, 2, 4)])
    K = G.as_finitely_presented_group()
```

(2)

Z/NZ x Z/NZ semi direct Z/MZ

Comment: You might get a faster answer on [Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org).